# How to convert an ArrayList<PyObject> to an ArrayList<Scalar>?

Tags: python, java, chaquopy

I have integrated a java developed app in android studio with python files using chaquopy. The python file returns a List however I am struggling to convert that List to an ArrayList format (In the java file after the list is successfully returned from the Python script)?

My code has the following

`ArrayList<Scalar> scalar_list;`

`Python py = Python.getInstance();`

`List<PyObject> obj = py.getModule("detect").callAttr("main", image).asList()`

`scalar_list = new ArrayList<>();`

I am trying to write the values of obj into scalar_list so that I can access each value
The format for obj is :
[[int int int], [int int int], [int int int], [int int int], [int int int]]

I have tried appending it but I receive an error "incompatible types  cannot be converted".
Any advice?
I have also tried using the toJava() function but has not worked to make it into Scalar format so that I can analyse each value of the arraylist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question suggests that your Python object is a 2D "list of lists of integers", but it's not clear how you want to map that onto a 1D list of Scalars. I'll give an answer for a simple 1D list of integers, and hopefully you can adapt that to whatever you need.

I'm also not sure what you mean by `Scalar`, but if you're referring to [this OpenCV class](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Scalar.html), then you could convert a list of integers like this:

```java
for (PyObject elem : obj) {
    scalar_list.add(new Scalar(elem.toInt()));
}
```